# form not filtering records

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file "revised Material Purchases" In this file are two forms, the main form is for filtering of records as well as editing of the records. The second form is the Purchases made form"new Purchases. In this form you input new records. The issue that I am having is that any new records that are entered are not appearing when you go back and filter all records. the record appears in the worksheet"Data"  but from that sheet you can also filter records(same as the main form). on the left is the records, the filter button places the filtered records on the right,however, any new recods(found on the left bottom)will not be filtered. Could you take a look at it and the code to see if anything looks out of place in the code? A fresh pair of eyes is what I need to find the problem.
Thank you for your asistance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share existing code and/or screenshots to better explain your issue.

Comment: Since you are not providing your code; you are probably using a range variable in your filter and are not resetting it after you add new data.

Comment: I have since resolved a portion of the problem however When sending data to a worksheet the record is transferred successfully but the all cells that contain numbers have the green triangle(formula error guessing) and cannot be formatted as well as the cells with dates also cannot be formatted. This in turn prohibits those rows to be included in any filtering that is on the sheet. Is the form causing this behavior?⁬ I have  removed the 'unnecessary' greet triangle by going to "options"> "formulas" and un checking the box that gives you the warning but still the cells will not allow formatting.

Comment: Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()
'dimention the variable
Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
Dim TxtID As Integer
'set the variable
Set DataSH = Sheet1
'error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'set variable for the destination
Set Addme = DataSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Me.TxtDateofPurchase = "" Then
MsgBox "There is insufficient data, Please return and add the needed information"
Exit Sub

Comment: It has been stated that I may be using a range variable in my code why my dates although formatted as dates in the code and the worksheet are passed to the sheet as text therefore not being filtered in the results. How would I resft it after passing(adding) the data? this is the portion of my code that does the filtering in the above comment.